# Placing and styling the "Read all answers" for a interview question answer web page

Tags: user-behavior, buttons, hyperlinks, user-expectation

I have a blog where I post interview questions and answers. So for each category like SQL, Java etc I have separate pages. Where in each page I have a collection of questions and a link to their answers.

My query is the link that I have used I am not very sure if the user will understand that to read the answer he/she has to click on it.

Below is a screenshot...

[image]

In the above screenshot there are two links to answer.

- First the header itself - "Networking Interview Questions and Answers – Top 34"
- Second - the link at the end of the answer - "View all answers >>"

I did a lil bit of user testing, asked few member of my family to see the page, they couldnt make out that they had to click on these links to see the answer. I mean when the question list increases to say 30-50-100 the links are not that visible.

What are your thoughts on this. Should I use a button for view all answers or any other way to communicate this in a better way.

[Direct link to the page](http://careerbaba.in/2014/05/system-administration-networking-interview-questions-answers-full-list/)

Comment: Make them blue and underlined,then re-test.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would list all the answers on that first page, but hide them with javascript. The questions should look like hyperlinks (i.e. they should be obviously interactive) and have appropriate hover states.

1. The user is presented with a list of questions.
2. The user selects the question that they are interested in.
3. The answer slides down underneath that question.

[This is what I have in mind](http://www.donateblood.com.au/faq#faq_311)

Comment: That'd be my recommendation as well. The example is a little too red, though - coloring only the headline of an entry is enough, I think.

Comment: Take it a step further and just make it look like an accordion like on Twitter's Bootstrap by adding a "+" or "v" (arrow) sign.